# VisualStudio 2012 - C# missing methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have win 8 system with .net framework 4.5 and visual studio 2012 
I had some problems when I work on a metro style app and when I searched the problems I found results in msdn with some properties and events like textBox.keyPressed, Control.ModifierKeys and some more. visual studio says method does not exist.
do I have to download a class or something

Comment: There is a difference between what is accessible in a WinRT app and what is accessible in a Windows app.  You will need to read about those differences.

Comment: I think the two "examples" you gave, one is an event and one is a property, neither is a method. But *what is your question?*

Answer (score 1):

Framework which is used to develop Windows Store applications is a subset of .Net 4.5 framework.

You may to check whether they exists in msdn.

For instance `System.Windows.Forms.dll` library does not exist for Windows Store applications thus, `Control.KeyPress` event does not exist as you can not use dll mentioned above in a windows store application.

Comment: can I add that dll externally ??